# How to generate a task list showing time remaining

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, formulas

I have a task list in Google Sheets. It has several columns, but for the sake of my problem, I only care about two:

- `D` is the status column with text values like "In Progress" and "Complete"
- `F` is a number column for number of hours to complete the task

At the bottom of `F` is the total number of hours for the project overall.
What I want to add is an hours remaining cell, which would take the total number of hours in `F` and subtract hours based on a "Complete" status in the same row of `D`.

One way I can think to do this is with conditional formatting, changing rows to green when the status is changed to `Complete`. That I can do.

I can then Sum `F` by Color (green), and subtract that number from the project total.

That works. The problem is that there isn't a way to get the whole sheet to do that. I have to put a conditional formula in each row and modify it for each row.

In other words, for row 3, I have to use: `=$D$3="Complete"`
Then for row 4, I have to use: `=$D$4="Complete"`

This would obviously be a long and tedious process for a long task list.

Any better ideas how to solve this problem? Or is a script necessary?

Answer (score 1):

I would make a 3rd row , lets call it G, which would represent something like "hours in, provided not completed" and sum that column. You can just put in a formula in that column that goes:

```
IF(D1 <> "Complete", F1, 0)
```

Just drag that value from row 1 to end, and SUM it at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you very much.  That can get the job done, but not very elegantly.  One issue is that somebody might want to use that column and manually put how many hours they have left there (overwriting the formula).  Of course, I could protect or hide that column.  That's closer to done than I was though.  Thanks again.

Comment: Hi again! I ran into a similar problem and thought of a more elegant solution, using `SUMIF` I hope you can still use it: `=SUMIF(D1:D5;"=Complete";F1:F5)`